# Размер создаваемого массива

Tags: c++, c, память

Как ограничен размер создаваемого массива(с/с++)? Мб языком программирования или компилятором? Вопрос относится как к статическим так и динамическим массивам.
Буду очень благодарен за развернутый ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Размер массива не ограничен языком программирования или компилятором. Но, в зависимости от типа массива, он может быть ограничен различными значениями.

1. Статический массив, объявленный глобально:

```
    int a[500]={0};
```

Его размер ограничен доступным объемом виртуальной оперативной памяти, который регулируется операционной системой.

2. Константный массив:

```
    const int a[500]={...};
```

Здесь есть зависимость от компилятора и целевой платформы. Если говорить об обычных Windows, то массив обычно создаётся в оперативной памяти - и тогда см. п. 1. Если это микроконтроллеры, где скорость чтения ПЗУ практически равна скорости чтения ОЗУ, то он останется в постоянной памяти, и тогда размер массива ограничен размером постоянной памяти (с учётом содержания в ней иных данных, в том числе исполняемой программы).

3. Динамический массив.

```
    int *a=new int[500];
```

Такие массивы создаются в куче оперативной памяти. См. п. 1.

4. Статический массив, объявленный в функции.

```
    void f(){
        int a[500];
    }
```

Такой массив создаётся в стеке, и размер его ограничен размером стека. Он определяется как настройками компилятора, так и операционной системой.

Во всех случаях невозможно назвать конкретную цифру, все зависит от вашей целевой платформы и операционной системы

Comment: Просто добавление `const` само по себе не влияет на хранение и связанные с этим ограничения. *"Такие массивы создаются в куче оперативной памяти"* *"Такой массив создаётся в стеке"* - опять вместо времени хранения приплетаются многострадальные куча и стек...

Comment: @user7860670, вопрос был об ограничениях на длину массива, поэтому время хранения - не главный аспект. На ограничения влияет место хранения, а не время. Про const я указал, что актуально для контроллеров, фактически задаётся скриптом линкера.

Comment: Я к тому, что если например имеется запись `int *a=new int[500];`, то это говорит только о том, что объект имеет динамическое время хранения, а вовсе не о том, что он создается на куче.

Comment: @user7860670, если рассматривать вопрос только с точки зрения языка и его стандарта - то да. Но в этом случае на вопрос автора можно ответить, что ограничение на длину любого массива - `numeric_limits<size_t>::max`. Но при попытке аллоцировать массив такой длины неизбежно получим `bad_alloc`. Компиляторы при генерации кода следуют не только стандарту языка, но и документации на целевую платформу, в которой как раз и может быть указано, что объекты с динамическим временем хранения создаются на куче.

Comment: Эм, нет, с точки зрения стандарта теоретическое ограничение на длину любого массива получается в силу ограничения на максимальный размер объекта, который задается реализацией, а вовсе не `numeric_limits<size_t>::max`. Наоборот, тип `size_t` должен быть таким, чтобы в нем мог хранится этот максимальный размер объекта. Далее, реализацая может устанавливать и практические ограничения на размеры объектов, которые могут быть намного меньше теоретических. Далее, хотя объекты с динамическим временем хранения действительно могут хранится на куче (что и происходит по-умолчанию при использовании vc++),

Comment: пользователь может совершенно легально задавать метод выделения памяти для таких объектов и хранить их там, где хочет, в т.ч. и на стеке. А если объект имеет автоматическое время хранения, то это еще не значит, что он должен хранится на стеке.

Comment: @user7860670, спасибо за информацию.

Comment: также можно видеть ограничение на максимальный размер объекта/массива из-за того, что разница указателей должна умещаться в diffptr_t.

Comment: *все зависит от вашей целевой платформы и операционной системы* и от компилятора. Или он твходит в поняте платформы?

Comment: `Размер массива не ограничен языком программирования`. Ограничен. Максимально значение, представимое типом `std::size_t`, и есть та верхняя планка, задаваемая стандартом языка. Да, стандарт говорит, что `size_t` «всего лишь» тип, способный вместить размер любого объекта в байтах, но это и означает, что размер объекта (а значит и кол-во эл-ов в массиве) не может быть больше `SIZE_MAX`. Более того, некоторые языковые конструкции явным образом рассчитаны на то, что размер создаваемого объекта может быть вплоть до `SIZE_MAX` байт, но не более.

Comment: Например, `std::malloc` имеет параметр типа `size_t`, количество элементов, задаваемое в операторе `new []` приводится к `size_t` ([expr.new/8](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.new#8)). И даже при определении массива следующим образом: `int arr[10];`, константное выражение в квадратных скобках приводится к типу `size_t` ([dcl.array/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.array#1)). Другое дело, что конкретные реализации вправе накладывать (но не обязаны) дополнительные более строгие ограничения на размеры объектов.

Comment: Стандарт _рекомендует_, чтобы поддерживались размеры объектов как минимум в `262 144` байта ([implimits/2.17](http://eel.is/c++draft/implimits#2.17)). На практике обычно существенно больше. Например, `g++` [не возражает](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e764922b9c48503b) против структуры в `2**63-1` байтов, но структура размером `2**63` байта [ему не нравится](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/146417b68f28614b). О конструировании и полноценной работе со столь большим объектом речи, конечно же, не идёт, ОС и оборудование внесут дополнительные ограничения.

Comment: `ограничение на длину любого массива - numeric_limits<size_t>::max. Но при попытке аллоцировать массив такой длины неизбежно получим bad_alloc`. Ну почему же. Если абстрагироваться от привычных реализаций, то ничто не мешает типу `size_t` быть 16-битным (а указателям быть 64-битным). В такой реализации вполне можно аллоцировать массив из `SIZE_MAX` элементов, и причём не один. `разница указателей должна умещаться в diffptr_t`. По стандарту не должна. Если разница двух указателей не представима типом `std::ptrdiff_t`, [то UB](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.add#note-1). @Croessmah

Comment: @wololo вот в том и дело, что тогда любое вычитание указателей может привести к UB, если такое позволительно. Поэтому, можно видеть ограничения на аллокацию объектов большего размера. Пример из gcc: https://godbolt.org/z/7ezqxKvP8

Comment: @Croessmah, не, я не спорю, что компилятор может дополнительно ограничить максимальный размер объекта типом `std::ptrdiff_t`. На мой взгляд было бы лучше, если бы такое ограничение было закреплено в стандарте, но это не так. И как следствие, можно увидеть и [такой пример](https://godbolt.org/z/dhf89P9ez).